# Copy string from DOM

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a rookie problem.

I have div and I wanna copy the url from data-element= to .json file

How can i reach this?

```
<div content="" id="preview" data-element="http://thereislink" 
class="sampleclass"></div>
```

Comment: to save link into a `.json` file you will have to write some backend code, js can't work with files directly from client side (browser)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getAttribute`

```js
let x = document.getElementById('preview').getAttribute('data-element');
console.log(x)
```

```html
<div content="" id="preview" data-element="http://thereislink" class="sampleclass">Test</div>
```

Or directly use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

```js
let x = document.getElementById('preview').dataset.element;
console.log(x)
```

```html
<div content="" id="preview" data-element="http://thereislink" class="sampleclass">Test</div>
```

Comment: okay, as i understand i will copy text but how save it to .json?

Comment: saving it in json is different from original question

Answer (score 0):

To select an element you can use different [JavaScript Selectors](https://gomakethings.com/javascript-selectors-in-html/).In this Example I am selecting element by Id. To access any attribute of element use `getAttribute('attribute_name')` function 
**HTML**

```
<div content="" id="preview" data-element="http://thereislink" 
class="sampleclass"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var url= document.getElementById("preview").getAttribute("data-element");
```

Comment: okay, as i understand i will copy text but how save it to .json?

Comment: to save it to .json file you need some server side functionality to write and save json file